# Injecting own DBContext in CustomOAuthProvider

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have following code in my Custom OAuth Provider class

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        var allowedOrigin = "*";

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

I want to inject my own DbContext Class here instead of using this ApplicationUserManagerClass. Can anyone suggest a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Autofac and Web API you can do it like tis

```
var dependencyScope = new AutofacWebApiDependencyScope(context.OwinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope())
dependencyScope.GetService(typeof(ApplicationUserManager)) as ApplicationUserManager
```

With ASP.NET MVC, you can create an `AutofacDependencyResolver` to simulate a request